# Edit PHP JSON array value

Tags: php, json

I have an ajax system in place that filters results for a clients website.

We're implementing a filter for "venue type". Each checkbox will be named as: venuetype[typeHere].

Now obviously this will be passed to PHP like that, but all I am interested in is the typeHere part.

I need to check that venuetype is in the array, if it is then remove the venuetype[] and be left with just typeHere.

My PHP script is as follows:

```
$select = 'SELECT *'; 
$from = ' FROM venues'; 
$where = ' WHERE TRUE';
$opts = isset($_POST['filterOpts'])? $_POST['filterOpts'] : array('');

if (in_array("nocorkage", $opts)){
 $where .= " AND nocorkage = 1";
}

if (in_array("hotel", $opts)){
 $where .= " AND hotel = 1";
}

if (in_array("selfcatering", $opts)){
 $where .= " AND selfcatering = 1";
}

if (in_array("marquees", $opts)){
 $where .= " AND marquees = 1";
}
if (in_array("inhousecatering", $opts)){
 $where .= " AND inhousecatering = 1";
}
if (in_array("outsidecatering", $opts)){
 $where .= " AND outsidecatering = 1";
}
if (in_array("licensed", $opts)){
 $where .= " AND licensed = 1";
}
if (in_array("venuetype", $opts)){
 // Function to go here
}
$sql = $select . $from . $where;
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
while($output = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
   $return[]=array('id'=>$output['id'],
                'title'=>$output['title'],
                'main_image'=>$output['main_image']);
}
$json = json_encode($return);
echo($json);
?>
```

Could someone give me an idea of what I need to do, I was thinking PHP regex... Would this suffice?

Comment: no, you don't need regex. $opts['venuetype'] should be an array.

Comment: Instead of using <input type="checkbox" name="venueType[outdoor]" value="1" />, and getting the array key (outdoor), why not use <input type="checkbox" name="venueType[]" value="outdoor" />. Then in PHP, you simply loop through the $_POST["venueType"] array, and that will give you all the venue type (typeHere) values.

Answer (score 1):

lil bit off-topic

i would create my code like

```
function setWhere($array,$opts,&$where){
    foreach($array as $arr){
        if(in_array($arr,$opts))
            $where .= " AND {$arr} = 1"; 
    }
}

$wAarray = array("nocorkage", 
                 "hotel", 
                 "selfcatering", 
                 "marquees", 
                 "inhousecatering", 
                 "outsidecatering", 
                 "licensed");

setWhere($wArray, $opts, $where);

//... more if your code
```

instead of X if statements

**Explanation:**
Question was: Why does $where has an ampersand befor?

It's a reference to the variable

Example:

```
$foo  = "hello";
$bar  = "world";
function doSomething($str){
    return $str;
}
echo $bar;  //outputs: world
$bar = doSomething($foo);
echo $bar;  //outputs: hello
```

same with reference

```
$foo  = "hello";
$bar  = "world";
function doSomething(&$str){
    $str = $foo;
}

echo $bar; //outputs: world
doSomething($bar);
echo $bar; //outputs: hello
```

Comment: Bit off topic, but a great help.

On the function setWhere, why does it has an ampersand before $where?

Comment: its an reference. so the var you put in there gets manipulated. you could delete it and use a return instead. its up to you :) i prefere references :D

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure this is what you need, but if you use:

```
foreach($opts["venuetype"] as $typeHere => $venuetype){

    // $typeHere will iterate all the key names in the venuetype array

}
```